# How to define a task, run it in the future, and cancel it using Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-handler

I'm new to kotlin `Coroutines`. I define a `Runnable` and call it asynchronously in a function using `Handler` with a delay. The important thing is that the previous task must be canceled before each call so that it is not performed after the delay. This is my code using `Handler` and `Runnable`. How can I do this with Kotlin `Coroutines`?

```
val runnable = java.lang.Runnable {
    ....
}

val handler = Handler()

private fun myFunction() {
      handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)// This is important
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `Job` and cancel it:

```
private var job: Job? = null

private fun myFunction() {
  job?.cancel()
  job = scope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
            delay(3000)
            ...
        }
}
```